# Converting from unknown type to UTF-8 in python?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm running into some awkward code in this comparison function:

```
def compare(this, that, encoding="utf-8"):

      if type(this) == type(str()):
           this = this.encode(encoding)
      if type(this) == type(bytes()):
           this = this.decode().encode(encoding)

      if type(that) == type(str()):
           that = that.encode(encoding)
      if type(that) == type(bytes()):
           that = that.decode().encode(encoding)

      # there has to be a faster way...

      return this==that
```

The goal is to make sure `this` and `that` are in the same encoding before making a comparison. But this seems like an awkward way to proceed. Is there a more succinct approach?

Comment: The code is totally ineffective, because `encode` and `decode` don't modify the object in-place, they return a new object. This new object isn't being assigned to anything so it's thrown away.

Comment: Fixed, sorry. I'm new to the language :-/

Comment: Are you only trying to compare utf-8 and bytes? or anything to anything else?

Comment: input will be one of (str, str), (str, bytes), (bytes, str), (bytes, bytes), but which one is not known at runtime. I'd like to make both inputs unicode first (using utf8) and then compare

Comment: Python can compare strings to bytes out of the box -- you don't need any of this code.

Comment: However, if the input encoding of the bytes really is "unknown", what possible purpose does this comparison serve? It will be false unless (a) the strings are both ASCII or (b) the strings are both Unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way will be to convert both inputs to `str` and compare them.

```
def compare(this, that, encoding="utf-8"):
    // convert this to str
    if isinstance(this, bytes):
        this = str(this, encoding)
    // convert that to str
    if isinstance(that, bytes):
        that = str(that, encoding)
    return this == that
```